# function calls [javascript]

Tags: javascript

```
<script language="javascript">
function toggle(id) {
    alert('call');
    if (document.getElementById(id).style.display == "none") {
        alert('now visible');
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = "";
    } else {
        alert('now invisible');
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>

</head>
<body onload="toggle('image1');alert('test_body');toggle('image2')">

<script language="javascript">
alert('test_pre_function');
toggle('image1');
alert('test_after_function');
toggle('image2');
</script>
```

Looks like a lot of code but it's pretty simple so i think most of you won't have troubles with it. toggle() should toggle the display status of divs containing images.

When the user enters the site the divs should hide, when everything is loaded the divs should show up. (onload)

Strangely enough, the function in the body (not in the body tag) only work half, i get and alert 'test_pre_function' and i get an alert 'call' (out of the function), but that's it.
The code in the body tag runs just fine.

I find this weird because it's supposed to do exactly the same twice and one time it runs, another time not, so i guess i must have made some stupid mistake.

Comment: A Javascript debugger such as Firebug will help you solve these sorts of issues.  It will let you see the normally hidden Javascript errors.

Comment: @Schwerm: Okay i will most certainly take a look at it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Script is executed as soon as it is parsed.  If `image1` and `image2` haven't been parsed when the script is executed, `document.getElementById("image1")` will return null so `.style.display` will throw a "is null or not an object error".  This explains why the two alerts work - execution stops at the first `document.getElementById(id).style.display == "none"` line.

Move the script to after the image elements in the document and it should work.

```
<script>
    alert(document.getElementById("image1")); // -> null
</script>
<img id="image1" src="some/image.jpg" />
<script>
    alert(document.getElementById("image1")); // -> object
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing this?

```
alert('now visible');
document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
```

Comment: i know, it is the solution, i cant mark it answered yet though, have to wait 2 more min

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/hUDb4/

```
var toggle = (function() {
    // an object to keep state for elements
    var state = {};
    return function(id){
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = (state[id] = !state[id]) ? "none" : "block";
    };
})();


toggle("myid"); // none
toggle("myid"); // block
```

But the main issue here is as others has stated that the DOM isn't ready until the document is fully loaded.

Answer (score -1):

you have used alert in the body onload. basically once the alert will get executed, then it asks you to click `OK`. meanwhile the last function may gets delayed focus.

see below

```
<script>
    alert(document.getElementById("image1"));
    <img id="image1" src="some/image.jpg" />
    alert(document.getElementById("image1"));
</script>
```

Comment: That's some fantastic copy-pasting.